# How to make the listview can not scroll when the last item has showed in samsung phone（Android system）

Tags: java, android, listview

The listview can scroll always  even if has nothing in view ,but this is not what I want. And I have no idea about that.  Please help me.
I am so sorry for my best english!
Thinks

Answer (score 1):

You can use ListActivity, or ListFragment.
All you need to do - is make layout with ListView with id = android.R.id.list, and view, that has id = android.R.id.empty.
So when listview is empty, empty layout will be shown.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html
Read about it here.

Comment: The situation what I say is only happen on samsung-android-phone  ,oher device can not happen .Whatever, thank you

Comment: You can try to set <item name="android:fadingEdge">none</item> to your ListView style.

Comment: Could you tell me your email ? I can talk with you if I have your email address? My email is bjltxsp@gmail.com.